# Unity javascript How can I check if the bool is true from another script?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, boolean

So, I am making a game... And on that game I have a door and a Key... The door is locked but when you catch the key the door is unlocked...

I have 2 scripts... The script which belongs to the door is Door.js
and the script that belongs to the key is Key.js

EmptyObject > Key > Key.js
Door > Door.js

In my key.js I have this codes:

```
  public var hasKey : boolean;

  function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){

  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
   hasKey = true;
 }
```

and on my Door.js I have this codes:

```
   var openDoor : boolean;

  function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){

   if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && hasKey== true) {
     openDoor = true;
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach a script to your **player** and add a `hasKey` variable to that script because the player has the key not the **door** and use `getComponent` to get the variable from it
remember that the `hasKey` variable must be public to be accessible by other scripts
 
I named the script that is attached to the **Player** `PlayerStuff`

for key

```
   function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){

      if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
      other.gameObject.GetComponent.<PlayerStuff>().hasKey= true;
     }
}
```

for door

```
 var openDoor : boolean;

  function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){

   if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && other.gameObject.GetComponent.<PlayerStuff>().hasKey== true){
     openDoor = true;
  }
}
```

there is another version of `getComponent` it is like this if the first one doesn't work use the one below instead

```
   other.gameObject.GetComponent(PlayerStuff)
```

or

```
 other.gameObject.GetComponent("PlayerStuff")
```

Comment: The bottom note has to be `other.gameObject.GetComponent("PlayerStuff")`. This version should be avoided though if possible.

Comment: `other.gameObject.GetComponent(PlayerStuff)` is from the documentaion [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: Yes, but that has either `GetComponent<Type>()` or `GetComponent("Type")` (with a string). (It says your version in the declaration, but the actual example is different.)